# Multiple mechanical units with abb_driver

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working on a project that uses 4x ABB IRB6640 with IRBT6004 tracks. RobotWare 5.15, ROS Melodic.
In case anyone was going to suggest looking into using abb_robot_driver, unfortunately there is no way i can get EGM working with my setup.

The company that has commissioned the robots for me have setup the track as a separate mechanical unit within the controller. They have said that they are not aware of a way of setting external axis up in the same mechanical unit. Is this correct or do they just not know how to do that?

If i understand the [abb_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver) wiki correctly, this means i have to have 2 instances of the [abb_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver) running in the controller, one for each mechanical unit?
I have found the following post, which is somewhat similar:

https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_driver/issues/3

however this is treating it as 2 separate robots on the ROS side (unless i misunderstood it). In my case i need ROS to see each of the robots with their respective rails as as single unit. do i need to have 2 sets of abb_driver nodes running for each robot? I'm a bit unsure how to proceed and would very much appreciate any help.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377749/multiple-mechanical-units-with-abb_driver/) by [Dominik JBS](https://answers.ros.org/users/68781/dominik-jbs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-06**:
Related Q&A: #q315856.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm working on a project that uses 4x ABB IRB6640 with IRBT6004 tracks. RobotWare 5.15, ROS Melodic. [..]

I don't really have any experience with RW5 I'm afraid, so I can't comment on any potential differences with RW6 based systems.

> The company that has commissioned the robots for me have setup the track as a separate mechanical unit within the controller. They have said that they are not aware of a way of setting external axis up in the same mechanical unit. Is this correct or do they just not know how to do that?

re: single mechanical unit: the current implementation of `abb_driver` essentially starts only a single motion task. And as that single motion task can only control a single mechanical unit (in its current implementation), that's where the "in a single mechanical unit" comment comes from.

> If i understand the [abb_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver) wiki correctly, this means i have to have 2 instances of the [abb_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver) running in the controller, one for each mechanical unit?

Yes, that's one way to approach it.

> I have found the following post, which is somewhat similar: [ros-industrial/abb_driver#3](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_driver/issues/3).
>
> however this is treating it as 2 separate robots on the ROS side (unless i misunderstood it). In my case i need ROS to see each of the robots with their respective rails as as single unit. do i need to have 2 sets of abb_driver nodes running for each robot?

The setup discussed in [ros-industrial/abb_driver#3](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_driver/issues/3) indeed runs two driver instances per robot (in your case), which exposes two sets of action servers per robot. This removes the possibility to synchronously move all axes. If that's a problem, another solution must be found. If it's not a problem, then depending on how you interact with those action servers, it can be made to look like it's a single robot (MoveIt fi should be able to deal with that, but I'd have to verify, alternatively, a custom node could be created which splits a `JointTrajectory` in two parts, but presents a single action server to your application). From a `JointState`s perspective it's not difficult to pretend there's only a single mechanism.

If at all possible, setting up the ABB controller with the robot + track as a single mechanical unit would probably be the easiest way to get things going -- at least with the current implementation of `abb_driver`. Perhaps a quick call to your local ABB branch office to get confirmation whether that would be possible with RW5?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dominik JBS](https://answers.ros.org/users/68781/dominik-jbs/) on 2021-05-06**:
Thank you for your help! I will try and contact ABB and see if they can assist on this. I do need to synchronously move all axis, so am going to try and figure out if i can change the configuration of the controller.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-07**:
This wasn't necessarily meant as an *answer* immediately btw. It just was too long for a comment.